# Python reading and writing data columns invalid syntax error

Tags: python-3.x

Hey I have a code written but can't figure out where I'm going wrong

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot      # Importing functions
import math
import numpy as np

with open('StarData.txt') as StarData:     # Opens StarData database
    lines = StarData.read().splitlines()

#Set up the data arrays
StarID = []           # Star ID no.
V_Mag = []            # Apparent V magnitude
B_V = []              # Observed B-V colour
Parallaxes = []       # Units are in arcsec  
Parallax_Error = []   # Units are in milliarcsec
d = []
A_Mag = []

for line in lines:                   # Setting the columns
    Columns = line.split()    
    StarID.append(float(Columns[0]))
    V_Mag.append(float(Columns[1]))
    B_V.append(float(Columns[2]))
    Parallaxes.append(float(Columns[3]))
    Parallax_Error.append(float(Columns[4]))
    d.append(float(1/Columns[3])                      # Distance to star
    **A_Mag.append(float(Columns[1]-(5*math.log10(((1/Columns[3])/10)))))** # Absolute V Magnitude

print(len(B_V))
print(len(A_Mag))

# Plot the data - 
plot.figure(figsize=(20,10)) 
plot.scatter(B_V, A_Mag, marker='*', c='b', s=0.8)
plot.xlabel("B-V Colour")                                           # x-axis
plot.ylabel("Absolute Magnitude $\mathregular{m_v}$")               # y-axis
plot.title("Absolute Magnitude $\mathregular{m_v}$ vs B-V Colour")  # Title
plot.show()

File "<ipython-input-4-74db4c3fff3d>", line 25
A_Mag.append(float(Columns[1]-(5*math.log10((1/Columns[3])/10)))) # Absolute 
V Magnitude
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I put ** around the line of code that is outputting invalid syntax, any help is greatly appreciated.
May be obvious but new to programming and the site :)

Comment: ... what error ...  copy and paste
the error message verbatim ( word for word) into your question - including the stacktrace.

Comment: File "<ipython-input-4-74db4c3fff3d>", line 25
    A_Mag.append(float(Columns[1]-(5*math.log10((1/Columns[3])/10)))) # Absolute V Magnitude
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please use the [edit] button to add it to your question - like Patrick Artner suggested

Answer (score 0):

Some extra unnecessary brackets

```
A_Mag.append(float(Columns[1]-(5*math.log10((1/Columns[3])/10))))
```

This will work